# Z_DATA_ERROR in Plastic SCM

Tags: plasticscm

i sync with plastic scm server and when i update from work space Item .i give this error in plastic SCM .and i retry update and forced update but not work truly.what about this error?i restart my computer and and restart the service in windows services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are having problems with the zlib library.

I'm not sure if your machine is Windows or a Linux computer, can you please clarify it? The first thing you should check is if the error is coming from the client or the server. In order to help you on that the full error stacktrace is needed.

Here you can learn hot to enable the client log: http://www.plasticscm.com/infocenter/technical-articles/kb-enabling-logging-for-plastic-scm-part-i.aspx

Here you can find the x86 and x64 distributions of the zlib library, you can try to start the GUI & the update operation using the two of them depending on you machine and OS architecture: www.plasticscm.com/externalcontent/ziplib.zip. Replace the zlib library you already have at the client/server directory with the downloaded library.

If you are still having issues with it I'm sure the guys at www.plasticscm.net can help you with an online meeting.

Comment: I use Windows 7 Ultimate for connecting to Plastic Server on Windows Server 2008 R2 .i give this error at the client machine when i want sync with server.I resolved the Problem for this way : I remove the all of the workspace and repository in plastic scm and I twice reconfig the plastic scm.